# Трудно недооценить и переоценить

Tags: фразеология

Есть ли такое выражение "трудно недооценить" и что оно значит?

Answer (score 1):

Чаще, конечно, встречается фраза **нельзя недооценить, недооценивать**. Она прменима в различных ситуациях: и в качестве совета, предостережения, и в качестве комплимента. А вот **трудно недооценить** то, что что очевидно, как **трудно непонять**, и это может походить на сарказм. Например: - Вы недооцениваеете мои умственные способности! - О, у вас такой широкий лоб, что наличие мозга очевидно и ваши способности трудно недооценить!..

Answer (score 0):

Очень странное выражение. Говорят обычно **"трудно переоценить"**.

Хотя, если вдуматься, понять и эту фразу  можно. ***Трудно недооценить*** - значит вероятна только высокая, достойная оценка чего-то.  В современном русском языке, однако, такое выражение встречается крайне редко.

Answer (score 0):

Сложно = трудно переоценить - трудно завысить оценку, потому что что-то заслуживает самой высокой оценки. Как бы высоко ни оценили - всё будет верно.

Трудно (сложно) недооценить - немного другой смысл. Это не "сложно занизить оценку", а "трудно не признать качество чего-то", трудно не заметить хорошего качества.

Недооценка - отсутствие надлежащей оценки, непризнание качества: недо = не.

Недооценить силы противника. Сложно недооценить (= не оценить) силы противника, если он их постоянно демонстрирует.

Недо и пере - антонимы в одном значении - "излишек, больше нормы" (пере - многозначная приставка). Недо - неполнота, недостаточность по сравнению с нормой, нет оценки.

Есть ещё и субъективность восприятия: Мне трудно недооценить Ваше желание разобраться в этом вопросе (потому что я его ценю, хочу оценить высоко, его нельзя не оценить).

И трудно переоценить вклад кого-то во что-то.

А вот "трудно недооценить вклад кого-то во что-то" уже как-то не сочетается. Например, фраза "трудно недооценить вклад Чехова в драматическое искусство" не смотрится, хотя по смыслу фразы  здесь недо = пере - нельзя не дать правильной оценки - синонимы. Получается, что возможны оба выражения, но их сочетаемость с объектом разная.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд - это бессмысленное выражение. Трудно означает степень старания. Можно потрудиться в даче превосходной оценки (трудно переоценить) и отсюда следует, что любая фиксированная оценка является недооценкой (сплошная недооценка). Но чтобы трудиться в плане недооценки...

Answer (score -1):

По моему легко "недо" и "пере",   то есть не попасть. НЕ прыгнуть куда надо. Попасть - это трудно. А вот перепрыгнуть действительно трудно. Но можно и легко. Оценить - трудно, переоценить, если вам это надо, то легко. Трудно переоценивать, бывает, если лень. Трудно недооценить, это когда раздумья, сколько заломить денег за товар, не в убыток, тут понятно. Но так не говорят.
Решайте сами по вашему вкусу, но так, чтоб понятно было, что вы имеете в виду.